# How to save multiple files in a chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to save multiple files to a directory - in one operation. If I correctly understand the [chrome fileSystem api documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html) this should be possible when I use the **openDirectory** option for *chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry*. Is that even allowed?
However, the documentation is very minimalistic and I also did not find any examples via google.

**More background:**
I have the proper permissions to access a directory and also have write permissions:

```
/*you need chrome >= Version 31.x [currently chrome beta]*/
"permissions": [
    {"fileSystem": ["write", "directory"]}, "storage", 
]
```

Then you are left with **chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(object options, function callback)** and **chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(entry entry, function callback)**, but I did not figure out if these functions are even what I want.

Here is how a *single file* can be saved to the file system:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type:"saveFile", suggestedName:"image.jpg"}, 
    function(entry, array){
        save(entry, blob); /*the blob was provided earlier*/
    }
);

function save(fileEntry, content) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
        fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
            fileWriter.onwriteend = null;
            fileWriter.truncate(content.size);
        };
        fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
        };
        var blob = new Blob([content], {'type': 'image/jpeg'});
        fileWriter.write(blob);
    }, errorHandler);
}
```

But how can I save multiple files when I use **chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type:"openDirectory",..}** or does **openDirectory** only grant me read-rights?

Comment: Follow-up on http://stackoverflow.com/q/28710804/632951

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this should work.

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type:'openDirectory'}, function(entry) {
    chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(entry, function(entry) {
        entry.getFile('file1.txt', {create:true}, function(entry) {
            entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                writer.write(new Blob(['Lorem'], {type: 'text/plain'}));
            });
        });
        entry.getFile('file2.txt', {create:true}, function(entry) {
            entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                writer.write(new Blob(['Ipsum'], {type: 'text/plain'}));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: **Wow**. I can't believe this works, the tutorial is totally silent on it. How did you know of this?